# Azure running native win32 code?

Tags: winapi, azure, native

From this post i see we can run un-managed code in azure.

[Running Native Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_windowsazurenativecodevs2010_topic2.aspx)

My question is do we have access to all Win32 API's in azure, or are there any limitations. In general are there any limitations (which some of you may have come across) in running un-managed code in azure.

Thanks
Nakago...

Comment: Please be more specific in questions. If you want to use some specific API, name it. Your question is too general to have a concrete answer. The general answer would be: "In general there are no limitations" (when you use CLoud Service, a.k.a. Web/Worker Roles)

Answer (score 2):

Most Win32 APIs will work fine. But please note Windows Azure is a service environment, so in general it doesn’t make sense to call APIs like CreateWindowsEx.

In addition, by default, only core OS components are installed. Please install libraries like ATL yourself, if you wish to use them (via startup task or custom VM image). Please also manually enable Desktop Experience to use certain OS features. From my experience, I’ve tried to use Direct2D (to process images, but not render them) and Media Foundation, it doesn't encounter any issues.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.